# How to compare 2 array and display them in one table

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, one array contains staff info while the second one contains staff sales.

For staff info array it contain id and name while staff sales array contain staff id and total sales.

I tried to display those 2 array but when i tried only 2 data is display.

While i needed the id without the sales to be display also.

My Code :

```
<?php
$employees = [
    $i = [

        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "Aliff",
    ],
    $p = [

        "id" => "2",
        "name" => "Aina",
    ],
    $a = [

        "id" => "3",
        "name" => "Ana",
    ]
];
$employee_sales = [
    $i = [
        "id" => "1",
        "amount" => "500",
    ],
    $p = [
        "id" => "3",
        "amount" => "300",
    ],
];
?>
<!-- Next Table --->
<?php
// echo '<pre>';
// var_dump($employees);
// var_dump($employee_sales);
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    foreach ($employee_sales as $employee_sale) {
        if ($employee['id'] == $employee_sale['id']) {
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $employee['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $employee['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $employee_sale['amount']; ?></td>
            <tr>
        </table>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
<!-- Next Table --->
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $employee['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $employee['name']; ?></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
<!-- Next Table --->
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php
foreach ($employee_sales as $employee_sale) {
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $employee_sale['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $employee_sale['amount']; ?></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

I want staff id number 2 to be display also even though that staff didnt have any total sales.

Want to display the `amount = 0` because the staff didnt have any sales.

Comment: Do you really want a separate table with just one row for each sale?

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about the display result you expect? (edit the question itself is preferable)

Comment: `Want to display the amount = 0 because the staff didnt have any sales` : 
 if(count($array) ==0) {echo("didnt have any items!");}else{foreach($array as $item){}}

Comment: the first table is the combine one, while the 2nd and 3rd is just a table of staff info and staff sales. I want to combine it into 1 table on the first table as shown

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable that tells whether any sales were printed for the employee. If not, print a row with empty sales.

```
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    $sales_found = false;
    foreach ($employee_sales as $employee_sale) {
        if ($employee['id'] == $employee_sale['id']) {
        $sales_found = true;
?>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $employee['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $employee['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $employee_sale['amount']; ?></td>
    <tr>
    </table>

<?php } 
    }
    if (!$sales_found) { ?>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><?= $employee['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $employee['name']; ?></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <tr>
        </table>

    <?php 
    } 
} ?>
```

Comment: thanks, i will consider your answer. I see that variable $sales_found can be helpful. i will try to use it on my coding

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one.

```html
<?php
 $employees = array(1=> array('id' => "1" , 'name' => 'Aliff')  ,2 => array('id' => "2" , 'name' => 'Aina'),3 => array('id' => "3" , 'name' => 'Ana')  );

  $employee_sales = array(1 => array('id' => "1" , 'amount' => '500')  ,2 => array('id' => "3" , 'amount' => '300'));

  $data = array();
 foreach ($employees as $key => $value) {

   $data[$value['id']] = $value['name'];

 }

   $data1 = array();
 foreach ($employee_sales as $key1 => $value1) {
    $data1[$value1['id']] = $value1['amount'];

 }



?>


    <table>
     <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) {?>
     <?php if(isset($data1[$key])){?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $key; ?></td>
    <td><?= $value; ?></td>
    <td><?= $data1[$key]; ?></td>
    <tr>
    <?php }else{?> 
     <tr>
    <td><?= $key; ?></td>
    <td><?= $value; ?></td>
    <td>0</td>
    <tr> 

    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>


    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can reindex your arrays to be much easier to access data by employee id. Also, you can display all data in a single table:

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Amount</td>
     </tr>

<?php
    $employees = array_combine(array_column($employees, 'id'), $employees);
    $employee_sales = array_combine(array_column($employee_sales, 'id'), $employee_sales);

    foreach ($employees as $employeeId => $employee) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $employee['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $employee['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?= (isset($employee_sales[$employeeId]) ? $employee_sales[$employeeId]['amount'] : 0) ?></td>
        <tr>
<?php
    }
?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$employees = [
    [
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "Aliff",
    ],
    [
        "id" => "2",
        "name" => "Aina",
    ],
    [    
        "id" => "3",
        "name" => "Ana",
    ]
];

$employee_sales = [
    [
        "id" => "1",
        "amount" => "500",
    ],    
    [
        "id" => "3",
        "amount" => "300",
    ],        
];    

$id_sales = array_column($employee_sales, 'amount', 'id');
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>sales</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($employees as $employee) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $employee['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $employee['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?=
            isset($id_sales[$employee['id']]) 
                ? $id_sales[$employee['id']] 
                : '0' ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You could swap the ternary for the null coalescing operator: `<?= $id_sales[$employee['id']] ?? '0' ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below loop in your code.

```
<?php
foreach ($employees as $employee) {

?>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $employee['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $employee['name']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php
        $key = array_search($employee['id'], array_column($employee_sales, 'id'));
        echo ( $key !== false ) ? $employee_sales[$key]['amount'] : 0;
    ?>
    </td>
    <tr>
    </table>

<?php
} ?>
```

array_search is used to find the index of matching employee_id in employee_sales array, and that index is used to fetch amount.
If it is not found we return 0